# React-select with react-hook-form

Tags: react-select, react-hook-form

I have a credit card component. when user select expire month or expire year from select, I want to get value in p tag. Controller code is here, if I use render with controller its working but not giving error.

```
<Controller
 as={<Select options={years} />}
 name="expiryYear"
 onChange={(inputValue) => changeValue(inputValue.value)}
 control={control}
 defaultValue={null}
 rules={{
 required: true
 }}
/>
```

How it giving error when its null and get value in the p tag?
and here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-http-rbzfp

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use watch/usewatch to retrieve the input value:

https://react-hook-form.com/api#watch

https://react-hook-form.com/api#useController

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";

const CreditCardForm = ({
  cardInfo: { number, expiryMonth, expiryYear },
  onChange
}) => {
  const months = [
    { value: "01", label: "01" },
    { value: "02", label: "02" },
    { value: "03", label: "03" },
    { value: "04", label: "04" },
    { value: "05", label: "05" },
    { value: "06", label: "06" },
    { value: "07", label: "07" },
    { value: "08", label: "08" },
    { value: "09", label: "09" },
    { value: "10", label: "10" },
    { value: "11", label: "11" },
    { value: "12", label: "12" }
  ];
  const years = [
    { value: "2021", label: "2021" },
    { value: "2022", label: "2022" },
    { value: "2023", label: "2023" },
    { value: "2024", label: "2024" },
    { value: "2025", label: "2025" },
    { value: "2026", label: "2026" },
    { value: "2027", label: "2027" },
    { value: "2028", label: "2028" },
    { value: "2029", label: "2029" }
  ];

  const { register, errors, watch, formState, control } = useForm({
    mode: "all",
    reValidateMode: "onBlur"
  });

  console.log(watch());

  function changeValue(inputValue) {
    onChange({
      key: "expiryMonth",
      value: inputValue.label
    });
  }

  function changeValue2(inputValue) {
    onChange({
      key: "expiryYear",
      value: inputValue.label
    });
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <div className="form-group expires">
        <div className="expires__select">
          {errors.expiryMonth && (
            <span className="input__error-message">required</span>
          )}
          <Controller
            as={<Select options={months} />}
            name="expiryMonth"
            // onChange={(inputValue) => changeValue(inputValue.value)}
            control={control}
            defaultValue={null}
            rules={{
              required: true
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="expires__select">
          {errors.expiryYear && (
            <span className="input__error-message">required</span>
          )}
          <Controller
            as={<Select options={years} />}
            name="expiryYear"
            // onChange={(inputValue) => changeValue2(inputValue.value)}
            control={control}
            defaultValue={null}
            rules={{
              required: true
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CreditCardForm;
```