# Passing value to hidden input from dropdown menu in react

Tags: reactjs, input, react-select

I have react-select dropdown menu  and hidden input which I pass to form when submiting...
using useState hook I created variable which tracks changes to react-select dropdown menu.
Hidden input has this variable as value also. I thought this would be enough.
But when I submit the form, console. log shows me that value of input is empty despite that variable that was selected from dropdown menu is actually updated.

I mean variable that I have chosen console logs some value, but hidden input thinks that it is still empty.

Does it means I have to rerender manually page each time I change that variable so input gets it's new value using useEffect ? Which is bad solution for me, I don't like it, thought it would be done automatically.

Or instead of useState I must create and use variable via Redux ? Which I also don't like, use redux for such small thing fills overcomplicated.

Isn't there any nice elegant solution ? :)

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

        const [someVar,setSomeVar]=useState('');
        
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ mode: 'onBlur' });
  const handleFormSubmit = (data) => {
       console.error('success');
  };
  const handleErrors = (errors) => {
    console.error(errors);
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('hiddenInput')[0].value);
  };
  const options = {
    hiddenInput: {
      required: t('hiddenInput is required'),
    },
  };


        .......
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit, handleErrors)}>
         <Select
         options='...some options list'
         onChange={(value) => setSomeVar(value)}
        />
        <input
        name='hiddenInput'
        value={someVar} 
        {...register('hiddenInput', options.hiddenInput)}
        />
    <button>submit</button>
        </form>
```

UPDATED

Comment: Could you post the surrounding code, including the form and submit handler?

Comment: Also wherever you call validate and the validation function -- tbh probs just post the whole component

Comment: whole component is overcomplecated. I think this example is enough. I've edited my post. please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `getElementsByName` returns an array of elements.

You probably want

```
document.getElementsByName('hiddenInput')[0].value
```

I should add that really you should use a ref attached to the input and not access it via the base DOM API.

```
const hiddenRef = useRef(null)

// ...

cosnt handleSubmit =(e)=>{
    console.log(hiddenRef.current.value);

}

// ...

  <input
    name='hiddenInput'
    value={someVar} 
    ref={hiddenRef}
    />
```

However as you are using `react-hook-form` you need to be interacting with its state store so the library knows the value.

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue
  } = useForm({ mode: 'onBlur' });

// ...
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit, handleErrors)}>
         <Select
         options='...some options list'
         onChange={(value) => setValue('hiddenInput', value)}
        />
        <input
        name='hiddenInput'
        {...register('hiddenInput', options.hiddenInput)}
        />
    <button>submit</button>
        </form>
```

You can remove `const [someVar,setSomeVar]=useState('');`

**However**, this hidden input is not really necessary as you mention in comments. You just need to bind the dropdown to react hook form.

```
// controller is imported from react hook form

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit, handleErrors)}>
<Controller
 control={control} // THIS IS FROM useForm return
  name="yourDropdown"
  rules={{required: true}}
  render={({
    field: { onChange, value, name, ref }
  }) => (
       <Select
         options={options}
         inputRef={ref}
         value={options.find(c => c.value === value)}
         onChange={val => onChange(val.value)}
        />
  )}
/>
  
    <button>submit</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: ok u are right, probably I have problems with validation then ? can I edit my post and show validation ?

Comment: Sure, though doesnt this solve your issue...is there more to it?

Comment: Please have a look at updated version. It seems to me I have to do something with my validation then. cause useState works and when I console.log 
document.getElementsByName('hiddenInput')[0].value
in error block it shows some value. But validation thinks it's empty

Comment: Let me take a look

Comment: Right so I think your main issue here is you using `react-hook-form`, but not really using it as its designed. In `react-hook-form` the values are managed internally by that lib and you dont want to register any `value` or `onChange` props since those are already returned from `register`. Internally, react hook form is looking at its stored value for that field, which will be empty since it has no initial value set and the dropdown is not changing react hook forms state. Give me some mins to add to my answer.

Comment: If so maybe there is way to validate react-select dropdown menu directly ?
I did not find how to do that and this hiddenInput was just workaround of that problem, I don't need it actually and in dropDown menu I have onChange and I actually change it

Comment: Edited. Right yes, I did feel something was off here. The hidden input is not really necessary. What you really need is to properly bind `<Select>`. Give me a bit more time to edit further :D

Comment: Done. Let me know if that doesnt work -- binding third party components can sometimes be a bit trickier depending on the api of the lib

Comment: Actually needs more fixing, give me a sec

Comment: Ok done. This assumed `options` is an array of objects and each has a `value` property in it

Comment: damn that's overcomplecated for me now :) what's that controller ? By the way I have actually several such selects. Should write them all inside that controller ?

Comment: Yeh its a little annoying. Basically it helps you bind 3rd party libs to react hook form. See https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller. I would probaly break his out into a new component that you pass props down into (that new component would have the controller in it) so you dont end up doing it lots of times.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66317381/react-select-with-react-hook-form, there is a slightly more neat controller implementation there.

Comment: You solution is probably right, but I don' like overcomplicated things and also I'm lazy :)
So I went the best easy and weird way :)
I will use both select and hidden input. And for hidden input to work I simulate input change using this func :)
https://jetrockets.com/blog/onchange-trigger-example-with-react
Works for me so I'm happy :))) 
And thanks for your helping I pulled several nice things from your explanations. Thanks a lot!